# when i try to run my project i get the error that says no module named flask

Tags: python

when I try to run my project I get the following error and it says no module named flask
I am using python 3.10 and it is the first time to get this error i used pywhatkit before and it worked

the error

```
File "D:\pythonProject\pypot\venv\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\remotekit.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install flask from https://pypi.org/

You can do so with the command:  `pip install flask`

Or better, you create an virtual environnement and install flask in it

```
python -m venv myFlaskProject
.\myFlaskProject\Scripts\activate # windows
source ./myFlaskProject/bin/activate # MacOS, Linux
pip install flask
```